# DevExpress XAF Return PDF document from Action_Execute in Viewcontroller

Tags: devexpress, xaf

I am developing an application which require to generate PDF against invoice in given format.

In previous version (based on ASP.NET MVC) I was using iTextSharp to create PDFDocument.

I want to know that How can I do this in XAF.

I successfully added Custom Action button in Invoice Detail View.

Can anyone suggest me how can I return the PDF generated by iTextSharp in XAF PDF Viewer?

Answer (score 0):

WinForms: You can simply display a regular form with the PdfViewer control from the Execute event handler of your custom Action. Refer to the https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraPdfViewerPdfViewertopic article for more details.

Both WinForms & ASP.NET:
Alternatively, you can design a report using the DevExpress XtraReports product and show its preview/export to PDF. Here are more documentation on this option:
 1. https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument3601
 2. https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument113601
 3. https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReport_ExportToPdftopic188